# How to serve a secured Google Cloud Storage file using BlobstoreService

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I wrote a servlet that runs on Google App Engine and serves a GCM file using BlobstoreService.

The file is secured using ACLs to be accessible only by users belonging to a Google Apps domain.

The servlet just does something like this:

```
    blobstoreService.serve(blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/"
      + "myBucket/"
      + "myFile"), response);
```

I'm getting a 500 error when trying to execute such code. The response has the following headers:

```
alternate-protocol:443:quic
content-length:323
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Fri, 08 Aug 2014 20:23:48 GMT
server:Google Frontend
status:500 Internal Server Error
version:HTTP/1.1
```

However, if I allow all the users to access the file:

```
gsutil acl ch -g AllUsers:R gs://myBucket/myFile
```

it works OK.

There is a way to pass some kind of credentials to BlobstoreService? Or secured GCS files can't be served using BlobstoreService?

Comment: What does the error message say? Typically, if you have a problem with access you would see an error code 403.

Comment: It only says "Internal Server Error". I added all the headers to the problem description.